# How to use function move_uploaded_file in wordpresss in function.php

Tags: php, wordpress

```
  add_filter("gform_pre_submission_filter", "combine_project_description");
function combine_project_description($form){
     $combined='';
     $combined.= '<ul>';
     if(@$_FILES['input_34']['name'] !=''){
        $combined.= '<li><strong>Attachments:</strong>'.$_FILES['input_34']['name'].'</li>'; move_uploaded_file($_FILES["input_34"]["tmp_name"], "./" . $_FILES["input_34"]["name"]); 
     } 
     $combined.= '</ul>';
     $_POST['input_33'][] = $combined;
     return $form; 
 }
```

How to add this code in functions.php?File is not uploading.Code is fine but file not moving to destination folder.

Comment: `functions.php` is normally located in the theme folder. Try `"../../" . $filename` to go back 2 directories which should be `wp-content` folder

Comment: _"I guess issue is in path"_ - Then you should do some proper debugging and check if that's the case. We can't do it for you. You could set up a constant in your conifg file with an absolute path to the upload folder. Then you can use that constant when moving the file where ever in your application.

Comment: @Second2None I tried with this path but file is not uploading anywhere.

Comment: Add the rest of your code and turn on debugging: https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress

Comment: Debugger shows no error.

Comment: add_filter("gform_pre_submission_filter", "combine_project_description");
function combine_project_description($form){
 $combined='';
 $combined.= '<ul>';
    if(@$_FILES['input_34']['name'] !=''){
  $combined.= '<li><strong>Attachments:</strong>'.$_FILES['input_34']['name'].'</li>';
     move_uploaded_file($_FILES["input_34"]["tmp_name"], "./" . $_FILES["input_34"]["name"]);
 }
 $combined.= '</ul>';
 $_POST['input_33'][] = $combined;
 return $form;
}

Comment: @Second2None my code is in above comment.

Comment: Put your code in the question bud, no one can read that.

Comment: @Second2None How to put code in question bud?

Comment: lol edit your question. Just under your tags you'll see `share edit flag`

Comment: @Second2None Could you please check now

Answer (score 0):

Code move upload file.

```
 if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_handle_upload' ) ) require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
    $uploadedfile = $_FILES['upload_captcha_background'];
    $upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => false );
    add_filter('upload_dir', 'my_upload_dir');
    $movefile = wp_handle_upload( $uploadedfile, $upload_overrides );
    remove_filter('upload_dir', 'my_upload_dir');
    
    if ( $movefile ) {
        echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
        var_dump( $movefile);
    } else {
        echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";
    }
    
    function my_upload_dir($upload) {
    
      $upload['subdir'] = '/sub-dir-to-use' . $upload['subdir'];
    
      $upload['path']   = $upload['basedir'] . $upload['subdir'];
    
      $upload['url']    = $upload['baseurl'] . $upload['subdir'];
    
      return $upload;
    
    }
```